# Django grouping queryset by first letter?

Tags: django, sorting, django-templates

I have a QuerySet like:

```
items = Item.objects.all()
```

Item has a 'name' field. In the template I want to show:

- A
- Axes
- Alcohol
- B
- Bazookas
- C
- Coins
- Cartridges
- S
- Swords
- Sparrows

So the items are ordered and group by the first letter. Missing letters are omitted. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a template tag for this, if all you care about is its presentation on the page.  First, define an organizational principle in the class.  In your case, it's the first letter:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...

    def first_letter(self):
        return self.name and self.name[0] or ''
```

And then define a regroup in the template, using the first_letter call:

```
{% regroup items by first_letter as letter_list %}
<ul> 
{% for letter in letter_list %}
  <li>{{ letter.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in letter.list %}
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, kind sir! :) That method inside the model was my missing bit.

Comment: very cool way to solve the problem. was looking at mixing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151631/django-grouping-queryset-by-first-letter/4151742#4151742 and this together https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/889/

Comment: You don't need the method on the class, as you can use filters in the regroup tag. You could just do `{% regroup items by name|first|upper as letter_list %}`

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to add that if you use this and your item has a lower-case first character it will be a separate group.  I added upper to it.

```
return self.name and self.name.upper()[0] or ''
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you could use `slice` inline in the template without the need for a `first_letter` method on your model.

```
{% regroup items by name|slice:":1" as letter_list %}
<ul> 
{% for letter in letter_list %}
  <li>{{ letter.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in letter.list %}
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: This solution is better IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Even easier. You can group by first leter just in 'regroup':

```
{% regroup items|dictsort:"name" by name.0 as item_letter %}
<ul>
{% for letter in item_letter %}
    <h4>{{ letter.grouper|title }}</h4>
    {% for i in letter.list|dictsort:"name" %}
        <li>{{ i.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% empty %}
    <span>There is no items yet...</span>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

`name.0` in this case the same as `item.name[0]` in Python.

Tested in Django 1.10

Answer (score 1):

For Django REST you can do like this,

```
import string
import collections

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, viewsets

def groupby(self, request):
    result = []
    for i in list(string.ascii_uppercase):
        c = City.objects.filter(name__startswith=i)
        if c:
            result.append((i, map((lambda x: x['name']),list(c.values('name')))
            ))
    return Response(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict(result).items())), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

## City Models

```
class City(models.Model):
    """All features model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=99)
```

## Response

```
{
    "A": [
        "Adelanto",
        "Azusa",
        "Alameda",
        "Albany",
        "Alhambra",
        "Anaheim"
    ],
    "B": [
        "Belmont",
        "Berkeley",
        "Beverly Hills",
        "Big Sur",
        "Burbank"
    ],
    ......

}
```

Comment: This is horrible. You're going to make 26 queries... This is NOT ok.

Answer (score 0):

*This is another take for doing in straight Django and Python. The other solution offered was terribly inefficient*

```
import itertools

collector = {}
item_qs = Item.objects.all().order_by('name')
for alphabet_letter, items in itertools.groupby(item_qs, lambda x: x.name[0].lower()):
    # you can do any modifications you need at this point
    # you can do another loop if you want or a dictionary comprehension
    collector[alphabet_letter] = items
```

What does this give you? A single query to the db.

Should I use a `collector`? No, you should maybe use a `yield` this is just a proof of concept.

What ever you do, DO **NOT** add a query call inside a loop.

Comment: Hi, I know i am late but the above gives me  a "itertools._grouper object" which i can't use, can you help?

Comment: @shreyansh Sure you can. `itertools._grouper object` is another iterable, notice the loop has `alphabet_letter` and `items`. `items` would be a generator, if you need to access it multiple times you would need to do: `items = list(items)` inside the loop. If none of this helps, add a new question and link it here and i'll address your unique issue.